# USB headset not working on skype on Xubuntu

Tags: usb, xubuntu, skype, microphone, headset

I've experienced some issues using Skype on Xubuntu. When trying to make/ receive calls, I've noticed that there is no audio, and I'm not entirely sure if my mic is working either.
The headset is 100% working on other operating systems (both Windows 7 and OSX). The headset is a Gamecom 780 USB. When attempting to change the input and output, there are no other options other than "PulseAudio server (local)". This is on all three; microphone, speakers and ringing. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Xubuntu, I have Kubuntu.

I was able to get the sound and mic on my headsets working by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then installing it with

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Start pavucontrol by typing

```
pavucontrol
```

in the terminal. It will open up a sound control window. Now make sure that duplex is activated by clicking on the configuration tab. Then look for your headset and make sure it is set to analog duplex (or digital duplex if it works for you).

You can then test your mic on pavucontrol itself then on Skype. I didn't change the settings in Skype, but you can see if your headset shows up after this.

Note: I am posting this answer on an old post as this post showed up when I searched for answers. This worked for me and hopefully it can help someone else.